# JQuery event handler for displaying hidden form in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have never used JQuery in Rails before but need it to make a button clickable so that it opens up a form(which is currently hidden) on clicking it -- The problem im having is in specifically using it in rails as I have no idea how and where to include the jquery code (so far I have installed the jQuery gems)

This the code in my view:

```
    <td>
        <div class="file_description"><%= object.metadata['description']%> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default edit_description">Edit</button></div>
        <div class="file_description_update">
          <%= form_tag({:action => 'update_file_info'}, multipart: true) do %> 
            Update File Description: <%= text_area_tag :description %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag :s3_path, file %>  
            <%= hidden_field_tag :prefix, @prefix %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %> </td> <br />
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </td>
```

Right now I have hidden the div.file_description_update class

This is the code I could possibly use for jquery:

```
 var hiddenBox = $( "div.file_description_update" );
    $( "button.edit_description" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    hiddenBox.show();
    });
```

Can someone please let me know if the jquery I am using for this purpose is correct and where and how I can include the jquery code within my rails app (which file?)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Im not sure whether I should post a new question but from the jquery code I have, I need to modify my existing code such that only one hidden div element PER BUTTON gets displayed ---right now --- with the code Im using clicking on a button displays all the hidden forms when I need only one form to display for each corresponding button --- Here are some additional details:

1. The HTML code is the same as in the original question.
2. This is the Jquery code Im using for button click:

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "button.edit_description" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
      $( "div.file_description_update" ).show();
    }); 
});`

1. the entire html code that I have posted as my question is within a loop so the 'td' elements keep generating each time for each file displayed in a table format ---hence, Im having the issue with the displaying of ALL the hidden 'td' elements within the table on clicking just one button (instead of just displaying that particular hidden 'td' element for the corresponding button)

Id really appreciate if someone can please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use coffescript ? Is jquery included in the application.js ?

Comment: @Vucko This is what I have in my application.js -                     //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

//= require jquery.ui.all

Comment: @Vucko I have a separate file for coffeescript as well but right now its empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct, but you need to put in the the document.ready section:

```
$(function () {
    $( "button.edit_description" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
      $( "div.file_description_update" ).show();
    }); 
)}
```

**EDIT:** If you need to use this variable put it outside this document ready section

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, I am displaying a list of files and each has the 'Edit' button. Right now,when I click on Edit for any one file --- all the Edit buttons of all the other files also display a form --- any idea how I could do it so that clicking on edit for only one filename opens up only that formbox and not the other buttons?

Comment: Each button should have an unique identifier id attribute is your best option. Don't know much about ruby, but presume these tds generate dynamically so basically what you could do is add increment suffix to class or id and then open the proper one. If not I would ask you for whole sample.

Comment: My sample is actually the same as above and I can use 'file'(for testing) as a unique identifier id. Im not sure as how to implement the add increment suffix method as well --- id really appreciate if you can guide me with some sample code regarding any of these methods.Thanks

Comment: Sadly like i said i don't know ruby, to solve this in java script is really ugly. I would suggest you to google a way how to increment html attributes with ruby code or maybe create a new question. But if your file is really unique i wouldn't bother with it, I would just maybe put the file name to id not class.

Comment: Assuming that the 'file' is the unique identifier, how would I add it to the jquery(im not sure about the jquery code) --could you perhaps give me a sample of the jquery code to open up a unique box(form) based on file id on clicking the button? --Id really appreciate.Thanks

Comment: I think we missunderstood each other what i was just refering to this selector "button.edit_description" which doesn't look like its unique but seems general which can come to this that not the correct $( "div.file_description_update" ) will open. Can you put up a sample of how html with 3 different files looks like maybe in jsFiddle in I will show you. Also we can talk through email as this is really not readable :) Youll see my email on my profile.

Comment: Your right: the "button.edit_description" is not unique for each file and Im actually not sure whether the "div.file_description_update" is unique as well (thats the confusion).  For the sample for 3 different files: I have a variable named 'file' which is incremented each time the code runs (the entire html code that i have posted as my question is within a loop with file being the incrementable variable)  --- could you provide me some jquery code based on this?